# Unable to start server after loading module

Tags: database, ubuntu, terminal, redis, redisjson

I tried to load RedisJSON module using redis.conf as it was said in instruction. So I wrote `loadmodule /home/artyom/RedisJSON/src/rejson.so` instead of the example with "#" and than my server crashed. I used `sudo systemctl status redis`  and got:

```
● redis-server.service - Advanced key-value store
   Loaded: loaded (/lib/systemd/system/redis-server.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2020-04-17 00:33:49 MSK; 17s ago
     Docs: http://redis.io/documentation,
           man:redis-server(1)
  Process: 11774 ExecStart=/usr/bin/redis-server /etc/redis/redis.conf (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 11775 (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)

апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Service RestartSec=100ms expired, scheduling restart.
апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Scheduled restart job, restart counter is at 5.
апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: Stopped Advanced key-value store.
апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Start request repeated too quickly.
апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: redis-server.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
апр 17 00:33:49 artyom-Lenovo-IdeaPad-S340-14IWL systemd[1]: Failed to start Advanced key-value store.
```

No doubt, module location is correct, because It worked fine when I didn't change `redis.conf` but used `redis-server --loadmodule /home/artyom/RedisJSON/src/rejson.so`. By the way, I tried some solutions from *https://askubuntu.com/questions/888726/failed-to-start-redis-datastore-server-ubuntu-16-04-1-lts*, but none of them helped. So, what is the problem? Why my server stops working?

Comment: what is redis-server version? on which OS are you running?

Comment: 5.05, ubuntu 18.04

Comment: What does the redis.log contain?

Comment: As I understand, there's nothing about current server. The last thing in redis.log refers to shutting down the server which I started using redis-server --loadmodule. So, my log is like: some number of lines about server start, with redis logo on the left side of them, and then another number of lines about server stop. I can edit my post with my redis.log or give you link to it (for example using pastebin), but I'm not sure it will help, if I understood what was in redis.log correctly. By the way, I did a mistake, my Ubuntu version is 19.10, I just forgot which version I had installed.

Comment: Yes, please edit and add the redis.log contents to your post :)

Comment: @ItamarHaber I have finally managed to cope with the problem. I read log again and found something about permission. I tried to google it and found question with the same problem on github (https://github.com/RedisJSON/RedisJSON/issues/105). There were your answers as well. But the only thing which helped - moving rejson.so to etc/redis/ like this man from github post done. By the way, on the road to success I broke my sistem as well by giving /etc directory all permissions xD. Anyway, I reinstalled system and now everything is fine - module is loaded. Thank you for the log advice!